# How to sum adjacent elements in scala

Tags: scala, collections

I want to sum adjacent elements in scala and I'm not sure how to deal with the last element.

So I have a list:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4)
```

And I want to sum adjacent elements using **indices** and **map**:

```
val size = x.indices.size
val y = x.indices.map(i => 
    if (i < size - 1)
       x(i) + x(i+1))
```

The problem is that this approach creates an AnyVal elemnt at the end:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(3, 5, 7, ())
```

and if I try to sum the elements or another numeric method of the collection, it doesn't work:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[AnyVal]
```

I tried to filter out the element using:

```
y diff List(Unit) or y diff List(AnyVal)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a better approach in scala to do this type of adjacent sum without using a foor loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a more functional solution, you can use `sliding` to group the elements together in twos (or any number of them), then `map` to their `sum`.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).sliding(2).map(_.sum).toList
res80: List[Int] = List(3, 5, 7)
```

What `sliding(2)` will do is create an intermediate iterator of lists like this:

```
Iterator(
    List(1, 2),
    List(2, 3),
    List(3, 4)
)
```

So when we chain `map(_.sum)`, we will map each inner `List` to it's own sum. `toList` will convert the `Iterator` back into a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try pattern matching and tail recursion also.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def f(l:List[Int],r :List[Int]=Nil):List[Int] = {
l match {
    case x :: xs :: xss => 
    f(l.tail, r :+ (x + xs))
    case _ => r
}
}



scala> f(List(1,2,3,4))
res4: List[Int] = List(3, 5, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for comprehension by zipping two lists, the second with the first item dropped,

```
for ( (a,b) <- x zip x.drop(1) ) yield a+b
```

which results in

```
List(3, 5, 7)
```